# How to search *just* the current line

Tags: search, csv

I'm working with large, extra wide data files I probably should just be viewing in Excel... but I'd rather stay in Emacs. Is there an elisp function to search (and fontify) just on the current line?

Comment: You can select the line, narrow to that region and do the plain old incremental search.

Comment: @kaushalmodi: Please post that as an answer (a good one). If an answer gets accepted then the question no longer appears among those unanswered. ;-)

Comment: OP: What do you mean by "(and fontify)"?

Comment: @Drew: isearch highlights matches, which is nice, but really slow.

Comment: I still don't know what your request "(and fontify)" means. You are apparently looking for some kind of highlighting of matches, but not isearch highlighting.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can tell Isearch how many matches to highlight at a time: option `lazy-highlight-max-at-a-time`. See also other `lazy-highlight-*` options. But this highlighting might treat a whole line at once; dunno. If it does, and these options don't help, consider filing an enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I didn't know about these options. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isearch is quite flexible and if you become tired of constantly
narrowing the buffer (as was suggested), you may want to have a
dedicated command for this, e.g.

```
(defun isearch-line-forward (&optional regexp-p)
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((beg (line-beginning-position))
         (end (line-end-position))
         (isearch-message-prefix-add "[Line]")
         (isearch-search-fun-function
          `(lambda ()
             (lambda (string &optional bound noerror)
               (save-restriction
                 (narrow-to-region ,beg ,end)
                 (funcall (isearch-search-fun-default)
                          string bound noerror))))))
    (isearch-forward regexp-p)))
```

Answer (score 10):

- Select the current line ( `C-a C-SPC C-e` )
- Narrow region ( `C-x n n` )
- Perform search using any method
- Go back to the original buffer by widening ( `C-x n w` )